# How to format a Shiny renderTable?

Tags: r, formatting, shiny

I am using renderTable in Shiny to display a data set, and I want to do some formatting for the table. For example, if my code is like below:

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  fluidRow(  
    column(4,
     ... ...
      )       
    ),
    column(8,
      tableOutput("mydata")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=11:20)
output$mydata <- renderTable(df)
})
```

This example only shows a very basic table. If I want to set the table width to 100% of the column width, while the column A takes up 70% of the table width and aligns to left, column B takes up 30% of the table width and aligns to right, and the background color of column names is set to blue, how can I achieve this using renderTable? Thank you very much for your help.

BTW, is there any document on renderTable format setting that I can refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "set the table width to 100% of the column width" but you can probably achieve what you need with the DT package. https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ and renderDataTable

For example (doesn't do the alignment):

```
library(shiny)
library (DT)
df = data.frame(A=1:10, B=11:20)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      df, options = list(
        lengthChange = FALSE,
        initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#42f', 'color': '#fff'});",
          "}"),
        autowidth = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(width = '70%', targets = 1))
        )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. In my ui.R, I defined two columns for output layout, one column is with width 4, the other 8. The table is displayed in the second column with width 8. By using the basic code the table length does not take up the whole column width, that's what I mean by "set the table width to 100% of the column width".  In this case, is it possible to use renderTable rather than renderDataTable to control the table width? Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to use renderTable, have a look at the documentation here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderTable.html. This points you towards the xtable and print.xtable functions whose documentaton  deals with alignment and width:                                         http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xtable/docs/xtable                             http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xtable/docs/print.xtable

Comment: I think Philips answer is Good, there's a error in the ui.R code that breaks the row before the table column and this is probably why it doesn't expand to the expected width. Also the default element width for table.dataTable is 100%.

Comment: Surely "set the table width to 100% of the column width" is unambiguous?